# Error inserting a record and retrieving the autonumeric ID with OleDb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

I am trying to make an oledb connection to an Access database to insert a new record and retrieving the key generated all at once. The code is this:

```
        private static int createUser(OleDbConnection accessConn)
    {
        try
        {
            accessConn.Open();
            //DbCommand also implements IDisposable
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = accessConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                //create command with placeholders
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "INSERT INTO EmployeeFiles " +
                    "([FirstName], [LastName], [JobTitleID], [SecurityLevel], [RowGUID])" +
                    "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @JobTitleID, @SecurityLevel, @RowGUID)";

                //Set Parameters
                string FirstName = "Dick";
                string LastName = "Tracy";
                int JobTitleID = 11;
                string SecurityLevel = "1";
                string RowGUID = "{" + Guid.NewGuid() + "}";


                //add named parameters
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                {
                    new OleDbParameter("@FirstName", FirstName),
                    new OleDbParameter("@LastName", LastName),
                    new OleDbParameter("@JobTitleID", JobTitleID),
                    new OleDbParameter("@SecurityLevel", SecurityLevel),
                    new OleDbParameter("@RowGUID", RowGUID)
                });

                int userId = 0;

                //Add @EmployeeID to the params collection and then retrieve it with Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                userId = (int)cmd.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value;

                //userId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                Console.WriteLine("user created successfully: {0}", deliveryId);
                return userId;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed creating the user.\n{0}", ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            accessConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

And when I run the code it throws this error:

**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter internal error: invalid parameter accessor: 9 BADBINDINFO**

I'm pretty sure the problematic line is this:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

And I just don't get where is the mistake.

If I comment that and the next two lines, and uncomment this:

```
userId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

It throws the error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Is there a way to get this working with OleDbParameter? So far I'm being forced to make the *insert* and then a *select* to get the key generated.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Try creating a new parameter with the name `@EmployeeID` and type of integer, then set it's direction and then add it to the paramters, it seems the same but might help, I don't know really

Comment: "Some database engines, such as the Microsoft Access Jet database engine, do not support output parameters": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(v=vs.110).aspx